# Passing 2 same object with different data as parameters, but only get the 2nd(last) object data

Tags: actionscript-3, object, parameters

I'm trying to set 2 object each with different data, and pass it into another function as parameters, but when I trace for the data in the object, I can only get the 2nd object data. Seems like the 1st object was replaced by the 2nd object.

```
TimeSpan.betweenMonths(MyDate.setDate(1984), MyDate.setDate(1988))
```

The Date Object:

```
package hwang.time
{

public class MyDate
{
    private static var _year:Number;

    public static function setDate(year:Number):MyDate
    {
        _year = year;       
        return new MyDate
    }

    public function get year():Number
    {
        return _year
    }
}
}
```

The Class the object was pass into:

```
public static function betweenMonths(myDate1:MyDate, myDate2:MyDate):int
    {
        yearArray = [myDate1, myDate2]
        trace(yearArray[0].year, yearArray[1].year) // both returnng 1988
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure to understand the need for a static function as opposed to using a constructor!

```
  package hwang.time
  {

     public class MyDate
     {
         private var _year:Number;

         public function MyDate(year:Number)
         {
           _year = year;     
         }

         public function get year():Number
         {
           return _year
         }
     }
  }

  //Then you can do...
  TimeSpan.betweenMonths( new MyDate(1984), new MyDate(1988));
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still return the same thing, since it's storing the value in _year, which is a static variable (and will not be stored with the newly created instance)? Just remove all static and that should work.

Comment: I overlooked the _year static variable! Of course, it shouldn't be static either.